# MySQL in directory of java project

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I am creating a Java Swing application in netbeans. I am using MySQL for database and I don't want to host my database online. So is there a way that I can move my MySQL database files in the project folder so that when I make the .exe file the database can be used in all devices.

Comment: Well yes and NO! You need the MySQL DBMS Server running to access a MySQL database. SO you could install it all in any folder you like, but you cannot just deliver the database files, NO!

Comment: You should consider using an embedded database like SQLite, Apache Derby, H2, or HyperSQL. These do not require a full-blown server. You can access the database directly from Java.